# Can we add more options in getopt?

Tags: c, unix, posix, getopt

I limited this code for now just to do some basic calculation like addition and subtraction so as to get an idea of how `getopt` works.

What I am trying to achieve is : `./a.out -a 20 20 -s 40 40` [result = `40` and `0` ]

I'm new to C, so kindly let me know the mistakes in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file1 = fopen("Results.txt", "a");
    char ch;
    int res;
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "a:s:")) != EOF)
        switch (ch) {
          case 'a':
            res = add(atoi(optarg), atoi(argv[3]));
            fprintf(file1, "%i\n", res);
            break;
          case 's':
            res = subtract(atoi(optarg), atoi(argv[3]));
            printf("%i \n", res);
            fprintf(file1, "%i\n", res);
            break;
          default:
            fprintf(stderr, "No such option");
            return 1;
        }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    printf("Opind = %i, argc = %i, argv = %i \n", optind, argc, argv);
    fprintf(file1, "\nWritten to file\n");
    fclose(file1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can add more options but AFAIK you cannot add more values to one option. What about `./a.out -a 20 -a 20 -s 40 -s 40`?

Comment: didn't work though, it returned the same values, any suggested enhancements?

Comment: You need to handle wach occurance separately and execute the operation after parsing. For add/subtract its probably better to not use getopt but parse on your own.

Comment: I'll look into it the next time i use getopt, i am pretty new with it so i was tryna figure out its working. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: You can by using and incrementing `optind` (see @charlie's answer for more details) but you should not. It is a very uncommon usage of options that will disturb any user. Long story short: you are using the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should define `ch` as `int` to accommodate for the possible return values of `getopt`. `getopt` returns an `int` that is either a matching option character or the value `-1` if no more options are present in the `argv` array. The `char` type is unsigned by default on some platforms (and it is a sensible choice to make it so), hence on these platforms `ch != EOF` will be always true.
- the return value of `getopt` when there are no more options is `-1`, not `EOF` which is very commonly defined as `-1` but only specified as being negative.
- You do not check if `fopen()` succeeded, producing undefined behavior if the file cannot be created or open for writing in append mode.
- you do not check if there are enough arguments for the `-a` and `-s` options.
- the second argument to `add` and `subtract` is always `argv[3]`. It should be the next argument in the `argv` array, `argv[optind]`, and you should skip it after use.
- `argv` canot be passed to `printf` for the `%i` conversion specifier. It is unclear what you intend to do by that.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file1 = fopen("Results.txt", "a");
    int ch, res;

    if (file1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open Results.txt for appending: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "a:s:")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
          case 'a':
            if (optind >= argc) {
                fprintf(stderr, "not enough arguments\n");
                return 1;
            }
            res = add(atoi(optarg), atoi(argv[optind]));
            optind++;
            //printf("%i\n", res);
            fprintf(file1, "%i\n", res);
            break;
          case 's':
            if (optind >= argc) {
                fprintf(stderr, "not enough arguments\n");
                return 1;
            }
            res = subtract(atoi(optarg), atoi(argv[optind]));
            optind++;
            //printf("%i\n", res);
            fprintf(file1, "%i\n", res);
            break;
          default:
            fprintf(stderr, "No such option");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    printf("Opind = %i, argc = %i\n", optind, argc);
    fprintf(file1, "\nWritten to file\n");
    fclose(file1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem and did help me understand getopt more properly, pardon me for a bad code. About argv in printf, i actually wanted to check the values if they incremented or not.